# Java convert bytes to binary safe string

Tags: java, redis, binary-data

I have some data in bytes, and I want to put them into Redis, but Redis only accepts binary safe string, and my data has some binary non-safe bytes. So how can I convert these bytes into  binary safe string so that I can save them to Redis?

Base64 works for me, but it makes data larger, any better idea?

UPDATE: I want to serialize my protobuf object to Redis, and the serialized data has '\x00', so when I read the data from Redis, I can not deserialize the data to object. Then I tried base64, it works fine, but with larger size.

So I want to figure out how to serialize binary data (protobuf object) to Redis safely and with smaller size

Comment: Do you have details of *exactly* what is meant by "binary safe string"? It's not a standard term.

Comment: [Reading this](http://redis.io/topics/data-types), it seems that for Redis, binary safe just means that Redis won't change the content. Unless I'm missing something (prettly likely, as I haven't used Redis before), you don't need to do anything to your data.

Comment: @Pablo I've update my question for more details

Comment: @JonSkeet I've update my question for more details

Comment: @MartinLuo: Your edit doesn't give any more information about what is meant by "binary safe string".

Answer (score 2):

You could try ISO-8859-1 encoding.  This uses a one to one mapping between bytes and chars.

This could still result in corruption depending on why Redis need this "binary safe" string.  You may have to use base64.

Comment: I want to find a way with smaller size, base64 works for me now, but I don't think it is good enough

Comment: If using `ISO-8859-1` works you may find it doesn't increase the size. Base64 turns 3 bytes into 4 chars, this turns 1 byte into 1 char (and visa-versa)

Answer (score -1):

The only safe way to serialize a binary object (such as a protobuf object) is to base64 encode it.  Base64 has a 33% overhead but gives you the ability to safely convert from arbitrary binary data to text (such as for use in an xml file) and back.

Comment: 33% overhead or 166% overhead?  In many environments, every three bytes of data turns into will turn into four two-byte characters, i.e. 8 bytes total?